# I am able to reverse a string using JavaScript function but how to do it using a form input and button click in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

you may see that I am able to execute reverse of a word and print in console but how to implement it using input and a button click in Angular. Thanks.

Here is the stackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8qa4ws?file=index.js)

**Sample code:**

```
function reverseLetters(str){
  let stack = [];
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    stack.push(str[i]);
  }

  let reverseStr ='';
  while( stack.length > 0){
    reverseStr += stack.pop();
  }
  return reverseStr;
}

console.log(reverseLetters('Angular'));
```

Comment: There is no input and button click in your code. Even on stackblitz. Please add that in both places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add button and input field as

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputText" />

<button (click)="handleReverse()">Reverse</button>

{{ reversedInput }}
```

In tS, `reversedInput` will contain your reversed string

```
  inputText = null;
  reversedInput = null;

  handleReverse() {
    this.reversedInput = this.reverseLetters(this.inputText);
  }

  reverseLetters(str) {
    let stack = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      stack.push(str[i]);
    }

    // stack = [...str]; shorthand to skip above for loop

    let reverseStr = '';
    while (stack.length > 0) {
      reverseStr += stack.pop();
    }
    return reverseStr;
  }
```

[Angular Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9zpqrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Navnath, it worked as expected. 

Answer (score 0):

1. Add two-way binding to your form control with `[(ngModel)]="yourstringvar`.
2. add `(click)` event to your button like `<button (click)="onButtonClick()">lol</button>`
3. Create the `onButtonClick()` method and put your javascript code inside.

Comment: Thanks, but would have been good if you could have given some more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-inbox';
  _string: any;
  reversedString: any = '';

  reverseString() {
    let strStack: string[] = [];
    let _reverseStr: string = '';
    this._string
      .split('')
      .map((letter: string) => {
        strStack.push(letter);
      })
      .map((letter: string) => {
        this.reversedString += strStack.pop();
      });

  }
}
```

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="_string">
<button (click)="reverseString()">Reverse Str</button>
<p>{{reversedString}}</p>
```

I hope the above code will help you

Comment: Thanks Umar will try your suggestion.

Comment: Your are welcome